Not able to download more then 40GB data from S3 buckets through Spring Boot
I have an issue when trying to read more then 40 GB of CSV data from S3 Athena.

2024-06-25 18:16:25.447  WARN 509917 --- [pool-6-thread-1] c.a.s.s.internal.S3AbortableInputStream  : Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.

private static int saveResultFile(S3Object s3Object, String outputFile, List<ColumnInfo> columnInfoList) {
    System.out.println("This is the save file method.");
    System.out.println(outputFile + "this is output");

    String lastTwoDigits = outputFile.substring(outputFile.length() - 2);

    boolean hasData = false; // Initialize to false
    int totalSum = 0; // Initialize totalSum before the loop
    // Set the maximum records per page
    int maxRecordsPerPage = 1000000;

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(s3Object.getObjectContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
         ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile + ".zip"))) {

        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader);

        String[] header = csvReader.readNext();

        if (header == null) {
            // No header, return false
            System.out.println("No header found in the CSV file.");
            return NO_HEADERS_FOUND;
        }

        int recordsProcessed = 0;
        int pageNumber = 1;
        CSVWriter writer = null;

        try {
            // Create a ZipOutputStream to write to the zip file
            writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile + "_" + pageNumber + ".csv"), ',',
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER);

            // Write the header for the current page
            writer.writeNext(header);

            String[] line;
            while ((line = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
                hasData = true; // Set to true if any data is processed

                if (lastTwoDigits.equals("02")) {
                    // Calculate sum for sms_split column
                    if (line.length > 8) { // Assuming index 7 is the 8th column
                        try {
                            totalSum += Integer.parseInt(line[8]); // Assuming sms_split is an integer
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            // Handle parsing error if necessary
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                int lastColumnIndex = line.length - 1;
                String lastColumnName = header[lastColumnIndex];

                if (isTextColumn(lastColumnName)) {
                    // Perform encryption and decryption operations only if it's a text column
                    String encryptedValue = line[lastColumnIndex];
                    String decryptedText = decrypt(encryptedValue);

                    if (isHexString(decryptedText)) {
                        decryptedText = hexToAscii(decryptedText);
                    }

                    line[lastColumnIndex] = decryptedText;
                }

                if (recordsProcessed >= maxRecordsPerPage) {
                    // Close the current writer and create a new one for the next page
                    writer.close();
                    pageNumber++;
                    recordsProcessed = 0;
                    writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile + "_" + pageNumber + ".csv"), ',',
                            CSVWriter.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
                    // Write the header for the new page
                    writer.writeNext(header);
                }

                writer.writeNext(line);
                recordsProcessed++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error creating ZIP file: " + outputFile + ".zip");
        } finally {
            if (writer != null) {
                writer.close();
            }
        }

        if (hasData) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= pageNumber; i++) {
                String pageFileName = outputFile + "_" + i + ".csv";

                try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(pageFileName))) {
                    String zipEntryName = pageFileName.substring(pageFileName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(zipEntryName);
                    zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                        zipOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, length);
                    }

                    zipOutputStream.closeEntry();

                    if (new File(pageFileName).delete()) {
                        // System.out.println("Deleted file: " + pageFileName);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Failed to delete file: " + pageFileName);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Error processing file: " + pageFileName);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Result files saved successfully with decryption.");
            System.out.println("Total sum of sms_split column: " + totalSum);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No data found to save.");
            return NO_HEADERS_FOUND;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (s3Object != null) {
                s3Object.close();
            }``your text``
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return totalSum;
}


I believe it will be necessary to reduce the reading into smaller parts, which will help avoid memory issues and ensure that all bytes are read from the stream.

The message says 'Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET' , it seems to be an S3 limitation

Hi @EnilsonFilho, exactly data should be in chunks but how to do that am confused.

Hi @prakhar1807, I have provided an example in the responses. It is not necessarily the corrected code, but a way for you to think about possible solutions.

Hi @EnilsonFilho,The problem I encountered was that when using this code, the file stops inserting data after reaching 33MB. I don't understand why it is unable to read data in the second iteration.

Hi @Tokazio, what kind of limitations could please tell me??

On data at a time, i've you tried the proposed solution in the error message about the 'ranged GET' ? I don't know S3 but the message seems a bit clear

Hi @Tokazio am not able to read that .csv file  System.out.println("No header found in the CSV file."); //this part

You could perform batch processing in this way:
public void readPartialObject(AmazonS3 s3Client, String bucketName, String objectKey) {
    long objectSize = s3Client.getObjectMetadata(bucketName, objectKey).getContentLength();
    long chunkSize = 20 * 1024 * 1024; // 20 MB
    long byteRangeStart = 0;

    while (byteRangeStart < objectSize) {
        long byteRangeEnd = Math.min(byteRangeStart + chunkSize - 1, objectSize - 1);
        GetObjectRequest rangeObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, objectKey)
            .withRange(byteRangeStart, byteRangeEnd);

        S3Object objectPortion = s3Client.getObject(rangeObjectRequest);
        // Process the chunk (objectPortion.getObjectContent())

        byteRangeStart += chunkSize;
    }
}

You will need to adapt the code in your method.

Its not working after 1st iteration
